# list of strings until it reaches the string “STOP” using while loop

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

Write a function, sublist, that takes in a list of strings as the parameter. In the function, use a while loop to return a sublist of the input list. The sublist should contain the same values of the original list up until it reaches the string “STOP” (it should not contain the string “STOP”).

```py
def sublist(list):
    i = 0
    sub = []
    while i < len(list):
        sub = list
        if (sub[i] == 'STOP'):
            break
        print(sub[i])
        i+=1
    return sub
```

Comment: You never add anything to `sub`.

Comment: can you give me an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it you're trying to find "stop" in the list.
I would code it this way:

```
def sublist(string_list):
    sub = []
    try:
        stop_index = next(i for i in range(len(string_list)) if string_list[i] == "STOP")
        sub = string_list[:stop_index]
    except:
        sub = string_list
    return sub
```

You get the index of the first stop with next (fastest way).
Then you return the part of the original list that precedes the "STOP" value.
If there is no stop then you just send back the original string.

There are multiple misconceptions in your code.
First of all, you are using a while loop to iterate over values of i.
You should be using a for loop (for i in range(len(list))).

Your line `sub = list` puts the entire 'list' inside sub. Not just one element. You need to use `sub.append(list[i])` to add elements to sub one by one.

There are some other small issues, but I will warn you against one last one:
Don't use 'list' as a variable. list is an existing python object, the list() function. if you use it as a variable you overwrite it, which can cause you problems down the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the native way to take only part of lists using [a:b] as intervals

```
def sublist(list):
   i = 0
   while i < len(list):

       if (list[i] == 'STOP'):
           return list[0:i]
       i+=1
   return False
```

Comment: if i test that code with: print(sublist(['bob', 'joe', 'lucy', 'STOP', 'carol', 'james']))
print(sublist(['STOP']))
print(sublist(['jackie', 'paul', 'STOP'])) that only return 1 element of list

Comment: Sorry there is an indentation error, i'll correct it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how crucial the `while` loop is, but with a `for` loop you can easily iterate through the list:

```
def sublist(list):
    sub = []

    for x in list:
            if x != "STOP":
                    sub.append(x)
            else:
                    break;
    return sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def sublist (s):
    str = []
    i = 0
    while i<len(s) :
        if s[i] == "STOP":
            break
        str.append(s[i])
        i+=1
    return str
```

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and  help new developers understand the underlying concepts. This is especially important here, where there are several other older answers, some with _very_ similar implementations. Explain why you believe yours is a better approach. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?